# Parametrized Named Formulas - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Would there be a way to achieve the, without coding ?

Formula that displays a Matrix( 10 rows, 5 columns, values set to 5 ) below;

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("5|",10),"|")),SPLIT(REPT("1|",5),"|"))
```

To a parametrized version as below;

```
MATRIX(@rows, @cols, @valued) = MMULT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(@valued &"|",@rows),"|")),SPLIT(REPT("1|",@cols),"|"))
```

On a separate note, i shared this using the Sheets->Help-Report.A.Problem feature of the Google Sheets but there is no where to see/know what features are coming or will NOT come.

Or is there?

EDIT: without coding, I meant, without going into Google Apps Script coding. Built in formulas a way faster - and parametrization seems like the logical next step (to me)

Comment: True. But I was emphasising the convenience and clarity of aliases for formulas. Especially when building ever more complex formulas. 


I wish Google would let  know which features are being worked on.

Answer (score 1):

With say, named ranges as below:

A1 `rows`   10
A2 `cols`    5
A3 `valued`  5

then

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(valued &"|",rows),"|")),SPLIT(REPT("1|",cols),"|"))
```

can return *10 rows, 5 columns, values set to 5*.